# Neo4j SDN 4 node_auto_index

Tags: neo4j, lucene, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I'm moving from SDN 3 to SDN 4 and from Neo4j 2.3 to 3.0.1

I have a following Search Cypher query:

```
@Query(value = "START d=node:node_auto_index({autoIndexQuery}) MATCH (d:Decision) RETURN d")
Page<Decision> searchDecisions(@Param("autoIndexQuery") String autoIndexQuery, Pageable page);
```

Param `autoIndexQuery` in my test equals to following Lucene query:

```
(name:rdbma~0.33)^3 OR description:rdbma OR (name:mosyl~0.33)^3 OR description:mosyl
```

Right now

```
decisionRepository.searchDecisions(autoIndexQuery, new PageRequest(page, size));
```

returns `null`

but works fine on SDN 3 and Neo4j 2.3 and returns a `Decision` nodes.

This is my Neo4jTestConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.example")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Neo4jTestConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration implements BeanFactoryAware {

    private static final String NEO4J_EMBEDDED_DATABASE_PATH_PROPERTY = "neo4j.embedded.database.path";

    @Resource
    private Environment environment;

    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {

        // @formatter:off
        GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
                .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(new File(environment.getProperty(NEO4J_EMBEDDED_DATABASE_PATH_PROPERTY)))       
                .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.node_keys_indexable, "name,description")
                .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.node_auto_indexing, "true").
                newGraphDatabase();         
        // @formatter:on

        return graphDb;
    }

    /**
     * Hook into the application lifecycle and register listeners that perform
     * behaviour across types of entities during this life cycle
     * 
     */
    @EventListener
    public void handleBeforeSaveEvent(BeforeSaveEvent event) {
        Object entity = event.getEntity();
        if (entity instanceof BaseEntity) {
            BaseEntity baseEntity = (BaseEntity) entity;
            if (baseEntity.getCreateDate() == null) {
                baseEntity.setCreateDate(new Date());
            } else {
                baseEntity.setUpdateDate(new Date());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }

    public BeanFactory getBeanFactory() {
        return beanFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration getConfiguration() {
        // @formatter:off
        org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration config = new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration();
        config.driverConfiguration()
            .setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver");
        // @formatter:on
        return config;
    }

    @Override
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return new SessionFactory(getConfiguration(), "com.example");
    }

}
```

What can be wrong with my configuration and how to get it working on SDN 4?

**UPDATED**

Also, I have found the following answer [Can't configure node_auto_index with InProcessServer() SDN 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340619/cant-configure-node-auto-index-with-inprocessserver-sdn-4) but can't find ServerControls  and TestServerBuilders in my classpath.

This is my database index configuration:

```
@Transactional
public class SearchDaoImpl implements SearchDao {

    @Autowired
    private DecisionRepository decisionRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        EmbeddedDriver embeddedDriver = (EmbeddedDriver) Components.driver();
        GraphDatabaseService databaseService = embeddedDriver.getGraphDatabaseService();
        try (Transaction t = databaseService.beginTx()) {
            Index<Node> autoIndex = databaseService.index().forNodes("node_auto_index");
            databaseService.index().setConfiguration(autoIndex, "type", "fulltext");
            databaseService.index().setConfiguration(autoIndex, "to_lower_case", "true");
            databaseService.index().setConfiguration(autoIndex, "analyzer", StandardAnalyzerV36.class.getName());
            t.success();
        }
    }
...
}
```

Right now I don't know where in my code is a correct place for adding

```
Components.setDriver(new EmbeddedDriver(graphDatabaseService()));
```

as suggested in the answers below

**UPDATED 2**

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {

    // @formatter:off
    GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
            .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(new File(environment.getProperty(NEO4J_EMBEDDED_DATABASE_PATH_PROPERTY)))       
            .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.node_keys_indexable, "name,description")
            .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.node_auto_indexing, "true").
            newGraphDatabase();         
    // @formatter:on        

    Components.setDriver(new EmbeddedDriver(graphDatabaseService));

    return graphDatabaseService;
}

@Override
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return new SessionFactory("com.example");
}
```

The following configuration fails with:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getSession' defined in com.techbook.domain.configuration.Neo4jTestConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session]: Factory method 'getSession' threw exception; nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Driver: null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting the driver class name property, the EmbeddedDriver will create a private instance of the `GraphDatabaseService`, which is not what you want because you are initialising it yourself. Instead, you need to tell the Components class to explicitly use the driver you are providing:

`Components.setDriver(new EmbeddedDriver(graphDatabaseService()));`

This should wire up the components as you expect.

Comment: Thanks! Where this line of code should be added in my application ?

Comment: The simplest thing is probably to do it at the end of the GraphDatabaseService bean declaration, just before you return the graphDb instance.

Comment: Right now It fails with `Driver: null` exception. I have updated my question.

Comment: I have added it to  `@PostConstruct
 public void init() {
  Components.setDriver(new EmbeddedDriver(graphDatabaseService()));
 }` and now it works fine